# Ruby on Rails IMAP segfaults with Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault, imap

I was trying to do a simple test to pull emails from gmail following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862851/ruby-on-rails-imap). However, when I do this with Ruby 1.9.2p136 it throws a segmentation fault on this line:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true)
```

Using 1.8.7p334 it works fine. I had been running into a similar issue where ActionMailer sending with smtp would segfault in 1.9.2 and work fine in 1.8.7. I found [this article](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4413) which pointed out setting `enable_starttls_auto => false`. However, I don't see any way to push that through to IMAP. However, it seems related.

Comment: Seems the root problem is with macports openssl. This came down with mysql on my local dev environment. 
https://trac.macports.org/ticket/28582

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following environment variable:

> export RUBYOPT=-r openssl

You can do this from within your profile or see: [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)